# Centralised Vs Decentralised ? Single Point of Failure?

Tags: distributed-computing

In centralised System, there are a number of terminals connected to a mainframe, so does this mean, this has a single point of failure ?

Comment: Yes, there is are many "single point[s] of failure" in a traditional monolith.  The many pieces of hardware.  Even if the application is running across many machines in a single location, that location may experience intermittent or terminal outages.

Comment: Yes, Thank you. Also it's a scenario of vertical scaling (limited resources).